# How do I assign the file name from a list with for loop?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

Having trouble with displaying images. I know that if you want to display image you do it like below with commas around the file name:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='312971.png') }}">
```

But how do I do that if I'm using for loop and list?

The route:

```
pictures = ['abc.jpg', '123.png', 'xyz.jpg']
return render_template('project.html',pictures=pictures)
```

project.html:

```
{% for picture_url in pictures %}
   <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=picture_url) }}" class="img-fluid mb-3" alt="Portfolio Picture">
{% endfor %}
```